# 2 elements in 1 v.add vector java

Tags: java, oop, vector

For example, I am calling a scanner from the user.

```
double second = sc.nextDouble();
double multiplayer = sc.nextDouble();
v.add(second);
v.add(multiplayer);
```

And when I display the vector output these 2 inputs appear in 2 lines. 
Is there anyway to put these 2 elements in a single vector?

```
e.g. input second is 5.0
     input multiplayer is 1.4
```

display vector will be:

```
5.0
1.4
```

Is there anyway to make them in a single vector like

```
5.0 1.4?
```

Please help :(

Comment: How are you "displaying the vector"?

Comment: It is still a single vector. Just that the display is multi-lined.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth

ListIterator iter = v.listIterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
System.out.println((Double)iter.next());

This is how I display the vector.

Comment: @adarshr

Really? So if I try getting the vector at that index, I'll get both values?

Comment: @Jolene: A `Vector` is like a box into which you put objects. You've put two apples (doubles) into this box. So depending on which one you want, you can access them using the index. `v.get(0)` will give you `second` where as `v.get(1)` will fetch you `multiplayer`. However, try to avoid using a `Vector` in the first place. `ArrayList` is a more modern collection for you.

Comment: @adarshr 

Wow thanks. I wasn't aware of that. I'm quite new to programming and I'm trying ways to do it instead of Array. But thank you all, I will try to explore :)

Comment: @Jolene You are using `System.out.println` instead of `System.out.print`. `System.out.println` adds the newline. See the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html)

Answer (score 3):

First, do not use `Vector` use an `ArrayList` (see this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-java-vector-class-is-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated) why).

```
List<Double> v = new ArrayList<Double>();
v.add(5.0);
v.add(1.4);
```

- Using `toString()` of the list:

  The output from `v.toString()` is `[5.0, 1.4]`. As you can see there are some "extra characters" `[`, `]`, `,`. To remove these you can call `replaceAll` with the [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) `[\\[\\],]`.

  ```
  System.out.println(v.toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\],]", ""));
  ```
- Using a for loop:

  ```
  for (Double e : v) System.out.print(e);
  System.out.println();
  ```

Comment: You might want to explain the `replaceAll` and give the non-replaced output as reference.

Answer (score 0):

`for ( Double d : v ) { System.out.print( d ); }`

You may wish to put a `System.out.println();` in front of that, so that the contents of the Vector are printed on a new line.